# ruby rtesseract out of memory after few documents processed

Tags: ruby

I am using rtesseract to read scanned documents in a loop...I process the pdf first with rmagick to jpg files and then loop them and run this

```
files_to_convert.each do |tfile|

          image = RTesseract.new(tfile, :lang => "slk")

          final_text += image.to_s

       end
```

after some amount of documents (10-30) system kills the job with the message in syslog

> Jul  7 22:12:09 osboxes kernel: [114590.313430] Out of memory: Kill
>   process 23567 (ruby) score 510 or sacrifice child Jul  7 22:12:09
>   osboxes kernel: [114590.313468] Killed process 23567 (ruby)
>   total-vm:3569292kB, anon-rss:2867500kB, file-rss:0kB

so I tried to implement garbage collector with simple calling 
GC.start after every whole document is read and processed but there is no difference. After some amount of documents system just kills the job.

I have 4GB of RAM dedicated to the dev virtual machine and running ruby 2.2.3

thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What is the size of the files you're putting into `final_text`? GC doesn't help as you are intentionally putting everything into the `final_text` and that is probably something you need for whatever reason so not much is left else for GC to clean it...

Comment: As draganstankovic says, the `final_text` must be getting large... do you need all the images in a single file?  Could you write them to a tmp file?

Comment: I have thousand of pdf documents. Every pdf file might have 1-30 pages. In files_to_convert variable is one pdf splitted to many images (1-30) and then every image is being processed by rtesseract. final_text is cleared after every pdf is processed so it is not pushing all pdfs into one
meanwhile I upgraded 2.2.3 ruby to 2.2.10 and instead of 2.8-3GB of memory used when running now the same job consumes 800-1.2GB of memory and so far running fine so I will monitor it